# BGP configuration multi-hop ping not working

Tags: bgp, icmp

I'm learning bgp and studying on a simple lab I'm unable to ping a loop0 two hops away while the loop0 on the nex-hop router is reachable

Topology is simple R3-R1-R2, from R2 i'm able to ping loop0 on R1 but not the one on R3

All destinations are reachable only from direct connected router

All prefixes are present in bgp table and correctly advertised and also the routes in routing table of all routers as per logs below

R1

```
R1#sh ip route bgp | b Gateway
Gateway of last resort is not set

      192.168.0.0/32 is subnetted, 3 subnets
B        192.168.0.2 [20/0] via 10.0.0.1, 02:23:18
B        192.168.0.3 [20/0] via 10.0.13.1, 02:23:18

R1#sh bgp ipv4 uni | b Network
     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>  192.168.0.1/32   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  192.168.0.2/32   10.0.0.1                 0             0 2 i
 *>  192.168.0.3/32   10.0.13.1                0             0 3 i
```

R2

```
R2#sh ip route bgp | b Gateway
Gateway of last resort is not set

      192.168.0.0/32 is subnetted, 3 subnets
B        192.168.0.1 [20/0] via 10.0.0.0, 02:25:53
B        192.168.0.3 [20/0] via 10.0.0.0, 02:25:53

R2#sh bgp ipv4 uni | b Network
     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>  192.168.0.1/32   10.0.0.0                 0             0 1 i
 *>  192.168.0.2/32   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  192.168.0.3/32   10.0.0.0                               0 1 3 i
```

R3

```
R3#sh ip route bgp | b Gateway
Gateway of last resort is not set

      192.168.0.0/32 is subnetted, 3 subnets
B        192.168.0.1 [20/0] via 10.0.13.0, 02:27:45
B        192.168.0.2 [20/0] via 10.0.13.0, 02:27:14

R3#sh bgp ipv4 uni | b Network
     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>  192.168.0.1/32   10.0.13.0                0             0 1 i
 *>  192.168.0.2/32   10.0.13.0                              0 1 2 i
 *>  192.168.0.3/32   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
```

Also a trace from R2 should go through R1 to reach R3 but stops on R1

```
R2#trace 192.168.0.3
Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 192.168.0.3
VRF info: (vrf in name/id, vrf out name/id)
  1 10.0.0.0 5 msec 5 msec 6 msec
  2  *  *  *
  3  *  *  *
  4
```

And the BGP config on all routers (in order R1-2-3)

```
R1#sh run | s bg
router bgp 1
 bgp router-id 1.1.1.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255
 neighbor 10.0.0.1 remote-as 2
 neighbor 10.0.13.1 remote-as 3

R2#sh run | s bg
router bgp 2
 bgp router-id 2.2.2.2
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.0.2 mask 255.255.255.255
 neighbor 10.0.0.0 remote-as 1

R3#sh run | s bg
router bgp 3
 bgp router-id 3.3.3.3
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.0.3 mask 255.255.255.255
 neighbor 10.0.13.0 remote-as 1
```

Could someone please help me to better understand what's wrong?

Comment: Are your pings sourced from the loopback?  We need to see your configs too.

Comment: Just tried and it works fine, but why without source it does not work?
`R2#ping 192.168.0.3 source 192.168.0.2
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.0.3, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of 192.168.0.2
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 4/5/6 ms
R2#ping 192.168.0.3
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.0.3, timeout is 2 seconds:
....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/4)`

Comment: `R3#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2067 bytes
!
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
!
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 192.168.0.3 255.255.255.255
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.13.1 255.255.255.254
!
router bgp 3
 bgp router-id 3.3.3.3
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.0.3 mask 255.255.255.255
 neighbor 10.0.13.0 remote-as 1
!
ip forward-protocol nd` other routers are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ping without specifying the source address, the router uses the closest interface for the source of the pings.  So R1 will use the interface address connected to R2 (10.0.0.0) as the source of the pings.  But R3 has no route to 10.0.0.0, so it can't send a reply.

Comment: Adding a default 0/0 to both R2 and R3 and redistributing into bgp now it works fine. Thanks a lot, solved